# mobfox Ads in Adobe Air For Android Apps

Tags: android, flash, air, ads, mobfox

I recently signed up for mobfox Ads and on their site says it supports Adobe Air apps.

But on their git hub page there is no list of Air ane or Adobe Air app integration.

Not sure were to begin or how to start integrating mobfox ads into my flash / adobe animate / Air For Android games.

Any tips / Ideas?

Can anyone help teach me how to integrate MobFox Ads into an Android game that is created using Adobe Animate (Formally Flash CC).

Here is the SDK and Info.
https://github.com/mobfox?q=q&dp=undefined&dp2=undefined

Answer (score 0):

Given that AdobeAir is basically a packager for HTML code, you won't find an SDK specific for it.

It means, however, you should be using the [javascript based SDK](https://github.com/mobfox/MobFox-JavaScript-SDK)

Look at an AdobeAir [*Hello World*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html) app:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Hello World</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="AIRAliases.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function appLoad(){ 
            air.trace("Hello World"); 
        }  
    </script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="appLoad()"> 
    <h1>Hello World</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

And now look at an example of how the JavaScript MobFox SDK works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"">
        <!-- ad will be placed inside the div with id 'main' -->
        <script 
    class="mobfoxConfig" 
    src="http://my.mobfox.com/ad_sdk.js?cb=CACHEBUSTER&referrer=REFERRER_URL&width=320&height=50&pid=fe96717d9875b9da4339ea5367eff1ec&type=banner&refresh=3000"
>
</script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's as simple as including the library, and having a placeholder in which the ads will be displayed.